# Generate a valid private key from public key

Tags: performance, cryptography, shell

Given a public key, I want to generate a corresponding private key. I know this will take at least decades or centuries on average to achieve.

I am wanting to increase performance as my current code is not likely to finish within my lifetime. It does not need to use Bash or calling `ssh-keygen` as a new process each time if it increases performance.

The code I provide below:

1. sets the public key I want to break into a variable named `id_rsa_pub`
2. randomly generates new private keys until the public key matches the one I want to break

   1. provides status updates (shows number of attempts so far) after every 1000 attempts
3. prints a message when a corresponding private key is found

```bash
## SETUP

# 1024 bits is the minimum allowed by my ssh-keygen
# Generate private RSA key (-t) with 1024 bits (-b) into id_rsa (-f) with no password (-N) and empty comment (-C)
# ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 1024 -f id_rsa -N "" -C ""

# Show details of public key
# ssh-keygen -l -f id_rsa.pub

# Simulate loss of private key
# rm id_rsa


## ACTUAL CODE

function generate_new_key() {
    # yes to overwrite old key
    yes | ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 1024 -f id_rsa -N "" -C "" -q > /dev/null
}

# Contents of id_rsa.pub I want to break
# I generated a new one randomly for testing, so it shouldn't contain any sensitive information
id_rsa_pub='ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAgQCvuSATmaLfCPvWIs5K2+dScg9e2l11EqU7mS0atteklEm9M8paYsUPu1/KzlQp+6MXCFy3rDAWX7GcIiGovpI4llGm5fFmSwUI6U2E6zy+v7IKu0KdjMeIfCuXi8JWX1HovYSz3id3yTQc/RrHwymdXTjXog0SFXugQvk4WFw+2w=='

generate_new_key

attempts=1

while [[ $(< id_rsa) != "$id_rsa_pub" ]]; do
    generate_new_key
    attempts=$((attempts + 1))

    if ((attempts % 1000 == 0)); then
        echo "Trying attempt #${attempts}"
    fi
done

echo "Corresponding private key saved in id_rsa after ${attempts} attempts"
```

Comment: 1024 bits are completely out of reach. For smaller keys, the best way to crack RSA is to factor the modulus, for which various techniques exist. If you do that then it takes 2^80 operations to complete. The SHAttered attack  at 2^63 ops was equivalent to 6,500 years of single-CPU computations and 110 years of single-GPU computations.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting exercise.

I would try to simplify things a bit. Use **fingerprints** instead of comparing whole keys.
For example, here is how to get fingerprints for an existing key pair from file:

```
ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 
3072 SHA256:vtNNKQH3r+MhK5W4ZqUl9O6V/RZKOcoNK4QJQuxMjle kate@bastion (RSA)

ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa
3072 SHA256:vtNNKQH3r+MhK5W4ZqUl9O6V/RZKOcoNK4QJQuxMjle kate@bastion (RSA)
```

Different formats are possible, so choose one which you find suitable and stick with it.

When designing a **brute force** tool, I would usually keep track of the latest iteration value, whether it be an incremented number or the current position in a word list, so that you can **resume** the process after an interruption (or crash).
Here you don't really care, because there is no "seeding" and each call to ssh-keygen will produce a "random" key.

For your purpose it could be interesting to use a different tool to generate keys in a **deterministic** way and I found this: https://github.com/mithrandi/ssh-key-generator. Introducing **reproducibility** by removing **randomness** in seeding can help in the early stages at least, while you're **debugging** and testing your program.

You could even write a **unit test** to validate your code based on static sample data.

But we agree the exercise is theoretical. It's unlike to complete in your lifetime.

If you add **parallelism**, there is a remote chance of success. But renting out the necessary resources on the cloud or from a calculus center won't come cheap.

Suggested improvement: don't write the key to **file**, don't read the key from file. **Pipe** the results instead.

Tip: openssl should be able to do the same as ssh-keygen. Have a look and compare performance.

Comment: "Use fingerprints instead of comparing whole keys": what does this achieve? Wouldn't the extra SHA 256 be slower than comparing the string directly and potentially cause collisions? (SHA 256 is 256 bits, but key is 1024 bits in example)

Comment: "generate keys in a deterministic way and I found this": the README says "using any 32-byte input to generate a keypair ... and infeasible in others (DSA/RSA, probably)". The example I gave is RSA 1024, so not applicable.

Comment: @hflvegmnc: that's the whole point of it: cause collisions although they are **extremely** unlikely to occur. It could be that my understanding is wrong, but if you generate a different key with the same moduli isn't it what we want?

Comment: I mean collisions in the 256-bit fingerprints (fingerprint of key 1 might be the same as key 2, but with different primes). The [cardinality of RSA-1024 primes is ~2^1001](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/25083). 1001-256=745, so I expect that there are 2^745 collisions in the fingerprints if we go through every valid 1024-bit RSA key. That is, collisions are not "extremely unlikely" in this case, but with certainty, and extremely common.

Comment: "If you add parallelism, there is a remote chance of success. But renting out the necessary resources on the cloud or from a calculus center won't come cheap." No, never. Would probably require more energy resources than available in our solar system, and electricity isn't that cheap anymore.